# Accessing parent object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in javascript :

```
var x = {
    a:1,
    b : {
        c : 2,
        d : //i want value of x.a in here  
    }
}
```

I have read that accessing parent property like this is not at all possible. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The nested object could be part of multiple other objects, hence there is no single parent.

Comment: You might want to use something like: http://jsfiddle.net/34cooh91/ or something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/34cooh91/1/

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Nested objects don't have access to their hosts as in any other language as well.

You have to set the explicitly by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript object doesn't have a `parent` because you can have sharing. For example:

```
var a = { x: 42 };
var b = { y: a };
var c = { z: a };
```

here the object `a` is "shared" as sub-object between `b` and `c`, so what should be the "parent" or `a`? You can see the sharing because after executing `b.y.x = 99`, also `c.z.x` will show be `99`. A single javascript object may be reachable using different paths.

DOM objects on the other hand have a parent because the DOM is a [**tree structure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) and it makes sense to talk about "the" parent of a node.

If you add a DOM node as a child of another and the node is already part of the DOM it will be removed from where it is and it will be placed in the new position.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, but your case can be written like:

```
var x = new function(){
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = {
      c: 2,
      d: this.a
   }
};
```

Comment: This isn't the same. Check the console for this: `x.a = 5;
console.log(x.b);`

Comment: @abhitalks of course it's not change, because `a` storing primitive type

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var x = {
          a: {
               c: 1
          },
          b: {
               c: 2  
          }
}

x['b']['d'] = x['a'];
```

should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The parent reference does not exist in javascript. What you can do is build an helper recursive function that will parse all your object and add a reference to the parent. This will build a more complex object.

Here is a video which shows how to : http://blog.wax-o.com/2014/01/how-to-find-deep-and-get-parent-in-javascript-nested-objects-with-recursive-functions-and-the-reference-concept-level-beginner/